# Emberfire throwing permission denied error when api does not have authentication

Tags: ember.js, firebase, ember-cli, emberfire

I'm trying to use the [hacker news firebase api](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) in an ember app. I've wired up the EmberFire adapter like so

```
import config from '../config/environment';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firebase';

export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: new Firebase(config.firebase)
});
```

This is the items route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var self = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.$.getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json', function(stories) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 30 + 1; i++) {
          self.store.find('item', stories[i]);
        }
        resolve(self.store.all('item'));
      });
    });
  }
});
```

The way the api works you have to get a list of story ids from `.../topstories.json` and then you can use firebase to find the stories themselves with the ids.

This is the error I get when I call `self.store.find('item', stories[i]);`

```
Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

Seems like an error that would get thrown if the client wasn't logged in, but this api is read only and does not have any authentication. I can make a get request to retrieve an item with normal JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: What URL did you configure for your `store`? (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have this: `firebase: 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com'` in my environment.js. I've also tried `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0` and got the same result.

Comment: I looked at the structure returned from `topstories` and it seems the items are just referenced by their `id` in there. So you'll probably need `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/` for the `item` store.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped. It's now sending a request to `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/items/9520057`, so I just have to figure out how to remove the `items`